# Clicking on a flash button with Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I'm writing some tests with **Selenium RC (on C#)** for our project, which uses Ext.NET, and everything was fine, before I've faced the fact, that "Upload" button used for uploading files is made on **Flash**. 
It is inserted like this:

```
<embed width="63" height="30" align="middle" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="opaque" allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" name="adaxuploaderaddon1317040891508" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" quality="high" src="/CuteWebUI_Uploader_Resource.axd?type=file&file=uploader10.swf&_ver=1317040891509" scale="exactfit" onerror="adaxuploaderaddon1317040891508_onerror()" style="z-index: 123454; width: 63px; height: 30px; opacity: 0.01; background-color: transparent;">
```

So, at first I've tried this:

```
selenium.Click("//embed[contains(@name, 'adaxuploaderaddon')]
```

Of course, it didn't worked :) Then I've tried several variations, like using **mouseDown, mouseUp**, using **clickAt**, location element with css **(css=embed)** - but still, no luck.

In Google people say, that it's possible to click the button with Javascript, but I haven't found any good examples.

Does anyone faced this problem before?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can communicate with 'IJavaScriptExecutor' & 'ExecuteScript' and pilote your flash (search about ExternalInterface for more details). For exemple i take a youtube page, and pause the video :

```
 IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
 driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ac4hKSfQ9s");
 driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

 ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("var movie = window.document.getElementById('movie_player');"+
                    "console.log(movie);"+
                    "movie.pauseVideo();");
 driver.Quit();
```

So, this is a solution but here you not click but directly calling the AS3 function on click.

Hope that help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use flashvars to communicate with the embedded swf file.

Comment: Can you please give me an example of using flashvars for this purpose?

Comment: This thing requires changing embed code (adding flashvars parameter), and I'm not sure for now, that this is possible. Need to ask developers about this stuff. Thanks for this information!

Answer (score 0):

are you able to detect the upload button ?
if not use the object-id or class-id in the javascript that calling the flash used for flash upload button. Hope this may work.